Strict stochastic ordering and expectations of strictly increasing functions
Recall that (weak) stochastic ordering $X \leq_{\mathrm{st}} Y$ of real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ means $\mathbf{P}[X > t] \leq \mathbf{P}[Y > t]$ for all $t$. A standard property of stochastic ordering is that if $X \leq_{\mathrm{st}} Y$ and $f$ is weakly increasing (i.e. nondecreasing), then $\mathbf{E}[f(X)] \leq \mathbf{E}[f(Y)]$.
The related but less commonly used strict stochastic ordering $X <_{\mathrm{st}} Y$ is when $X \leq_{\mathrm{st}} Y$ and, additionally, there exists $t$ such that $\mathbf{P}[X > t] < \mathbf{P}[Y > t]$.
I believe the following strict analogue of the standard property should hold for strictly ordered variables.
Claim. If $X <_{\mathrm{st}} Y$ and $f$ is strictly increasing, then $\mathbf{E}[f(X)] < \mathbf{E}[f(Y)]$.
This is not too hard to prove in special cases (e.g. use summation by parts for integer-valued random variables). I suspect it should hold in general, but maybe there's some pathological singular-distribution counterexample?
Is the claim true? If so, is there a standard reference? If not, what is the counterexample?

We implicitly suppose that $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ have means.
If $f$ is strictly increasing and $X\le_{\operatorname{st}}Y$ (strictly), then $f(X)\le_{\operatorname{st}}f(Y)$ (strictly); hence we can suppose $f(t)=t$.
Since $X$ has a mean,\begin{align}
\mathbf E[X] &= \lim_{a\to-\infty} \int_a^{+\infty} x \,\mathbf P(dx) \\
&= \lim_{a\to-\infty} \Bigl( a + \int_{a<t<x} \mathbf P(dx) \,dt \Bigr) \\
&= \lim_{a\to-\infty} \Bigl( a + \int_a^{+\infty} \mathbf P[X>t] \,dt \Bigr) \text,
\end{align}which shows that $\mathbf E[X] \le \mathbf E[Y]$ if $X \le_{\operatorname{st}} Y$.
Now suppose that $\mathbf E[X] = \mathbf E[Y]$.
Then by the above calculation,$$
0 = \lim_{a\to-\infty} \int_a^{+\infty} \bigl( \mathbf P[Y>t] - \mathbf P[X>t] \bigr) \,dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \bigl( \mathbf P[Y>t] - \mathbf P[X>t] \bigr) \,dt \text.
$$As the integrand is $\ge0$, this means that the set $S$ on which it is $>0$ has zero Lebesgue measure.
But it is also right-continuous, so any point of $S$ comes with an interval to its right contained in $S$.
This proves that $S$ is empty, and so that $X\le_{\operatorname{st}}Y\le_{\operatorname{st}}X$.

The observation that $f(t) = t$ without loss of generality is nice, and makes even clearer the last comment from my answer. Thanks!

The claim is true. Suppose $X <_{\mathrm{st}} Y$. Then there exists $t$ such that $\mathbf{P}[X > t] < \mathbf{P}[Y > t]$. The key is that (C)CDFs are right-continuous (see this answer). Applying this to $Y$'s CCDF, this means there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\mathbf{P}[X > t] < \mathbf{P}[Y > t + \delta]. \qquad (*)$$
This is the key fact. To fill in the rest of the proof, one can use the standard inverse-CDF coupling, which constructs versions of $X$ and $Y$ on a common probability space such that $\mathbf{P}[X \leq Y] = 1$. One can use $(*)$ to show that $\mathbf{P}[X < Y] > 0$ under this coupling, implying
$$\mathbf{E}[f(Y) - f(X)] = \mathbf{E}[f(Y) - f(X) \mid Y > X] \, \mathbf{P}[Y > X] > 0$$
as desired. That is, things ultimately boil down to the following core fact about expectation: a nonnegative variable that has nonzero probability of being positive has positive expectation.
